# Will Razor's EditorFor() syntactic sugar create a checkbox list in the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkboxlist, editorfor

I've been jumping through hoops to add an array of checkboxes to a View in an asp.net MVC project (using a custom jQuery plugin), but just realized it might be possible using the "in-the-box" functionality of the MVC / Razor extravaganza.

Theoretically, the following should work:

If a model has an array of bool, such as:

```
public bool[] chicagoBoolsFools { get; set; }
```

...calling this in the View:

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.chicagoBoolsFools)
```

...should create an array of checkboxes bound to the Model member.

Is this the case only in theory, or also in actuality?

Comment: Neither. How could EditorFor figure out how many checkboxes you want?

Comment: Good point; is there a way to specify how many, thus allowing EditorFor to work as desired in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `@Html.EditorFor` doesn't even create checkboxes... Maybe I am misunderstanding you but I would try something more along the lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864801/mvc3-how-to-correctly-use-html-checkbox).

Try stuffing a model with either a list of Checkboxes (represented by a string and a boolean value) or just a basic string property for each checkbox, which can then be rendered in the view using several `@Html.CheckBoxFor` calls.

`@Html.CheckBox` or `@Html.CheckBoxFor` are key here.